# Determine whether a point lies in a Matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I've got a Matplotlib fig with several subplots. I want a function to be executed when the subplot in position 1 is clicked. From the event object that is generated by the event handler how do I determine whether or not the subplot was clicked?

Comment: Can you show us some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` object that comes into the callback as an attribute `inaxes` which is the axes which was clicked.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax_list = ax_list.ravel()
ax_list[0].set_gid('A')
ax_list[1].set_gid('B')
ax_list[2].set_gid('C')

def clicker(event):
    print(event.inaxes.get_gid())

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', clicker)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I then calculate the coordinates of the click within that subplot? For example if subplot 1 contains an image and I click on coordinates 0,0 of that image I don't get 0,0 when I access event.x, event.y

Comment: `x` and `y` are in pixel space `xdata` and `ydata` are in data space.

Comment: How would you then access (and set the data) in the subplots from a different method?